# is it possible to add navigationcontroller to a non-rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tabbar application and I would like to add navigationcontroller to a non-rootviewcontroller.

Is it possible?

Thanks for any help.

- UPDATE 23:10 GMT+2 
  [image]

Comment: What do you mean by non-rootViewController? Any view controller (except maybe splitViewController) can be embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: but I could not do it. I created a tabbar application and addded navigationcontroller to any viewcontroller which is not at the rool level and got following error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: With the structure you show, you would have to present the navigation controller modally. The other way to fix the problem, is to embed SecondViewController in the navigation controller instead (you could hide the navigation bar if you don't want that look).

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, as such you can present it or you can add its view as a subview (assuming you then don't release the `UINavigationController` instance itself which would have interesting side effects).

What you can't do is to push the navigation controller into some of the provided container view controllers. Like pushing a navigation controller into another navigation controllers stack.

Comment: I created a tabbar application and added navigationcontroller to any viewcontroller which is not at the rool level.Then placed a button and dragged with cntrl for push segue and got following error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.' If I add the navigationcontroller to the viewcontroller which is at root level, no problem occurs.

Comment: So you can only add push segues to views which are in the navigation controller. Otherwise the 'push' makes no sense.

Comment: I updated my first entry with the image figuring out the problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that each tab isn't a nav controller? Why a view controller and then trying to put a nav controller on it?

Comment: yes,because I have many items in my initial viewcontrollers and the size reduces when I add navigation controller additionally. If this method/way is not plausible, I can change, but if it's possible, I would really like to use.

Comment: Size reduces, you mean the navigation bar (that you can ask the nav controller to hide)?

Comment: Okay, I surrender :) Maybe I can change my mind and try to add the navigation controller to the root viewcontroller. But it comes interesting to me that why I cannot start a navcontroller from any viewcontroller.

Comment: Your screen shot (what I can read on it anyway) looks ok. So the question leads back to exactly what code is being used to show the nav controller...

Comment: I know the code to hide the navbar, but I will have to add "back buttons" in the next viewcontrollers at this time. Is it possible to auto-hide or smth like that?

Comment: In each of your view controllers, in viewWillAppear, add `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:... animated:YES];` with the appropriate setting.

Comment: and last question, do you know any mehthod to auto-hide/show when touch on screen. Because I need a back button for each viewcontroller. I also need to add back action programatically.

Comment: auto, no. You could use a gesture recogniser which triggers the toggle of visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Each Tab in Tab Bar Controller can have a custom view controller. Where your custom view controller can be a navigation controller.

But, in a navigation controller, if you wish to add a navigation controller on lets say tap of a tableview cell, you will have to present it modally on navigation controller. You can not push a navigation controller into another navigation controller.

for eg.

> 1. Instantiate your root view controller for the navigation controller you wish to present
>      YourAnotherRootVC *anotherVC = [[YourAnotherRootVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourAnotherRootVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
> 2. Instantiate UiNavigationController
>      UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:anotherVC];
> 3. Present it to current navigation controller.
>      [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

Comment: I updated my first entry with the image figuring out the problem.